# (VueJS v3) How would I watch for array mutations (inserted, removed, replaced) of an reactive array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

How can I watch a reactive array so that I know what is inserted, removed and replaced when `push()`, `splice()`, etc is called?

Comment: `watch` receives both new and old values - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html

Comment: watch doesn't provide new and old values for array types. only strings, booleans and numbers

Comment: Vue's reactivity system creates a proxy setters that intercept direct assignment to those variables.  Since push/splice etc aren't assignments *per se*, watching those vars doesn't do anything.  I can see how watching those changes would be helpful from a dev perspective, but I would question the necessity of such a watcher for production use.

Comment: i'm trying to create a component that watches for this changes and do entrance / exit animation for each item added / removed / replace. is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Since `splice` etc doesn't directly assign a new value to the array, Vue's reactivity system won't pick up on the changes and the watcher won't fire.

You can, however, create a computed that copies the array and then watch that:

```
computed: {
  myArray() {
    return this.my_array.slice();
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    my_array: [],
  };
},
watch: {
  myArray(newArray, oldArray) {
    // do stuff
  },
},
```

[Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score -1):

On Vue3 you can do this on your script

```
<script setup>
watchEffect(() => { console.log(nameOfYourArray)})
</script>
```

Or on Vue 2 and Vue3 with Option API

```
     Watch: {
      nameofYourArray: {
        deep: true,
        immediate:true,
        handler(newVal,oldVal){
        console.log(newVal)
        }
      }
   }
```

if you use 2 solutions  you don't forget to add deep otherwise it won't work on child array

Comment: This only works when the array var is directly assigned to, not when using array methods to mutate the array.